# In ActionScript 3 how do you change the behavior of a text box dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, textbox

I am trying to change the input text behavior from "Single Line" to "Password" and back based on user input such that when the user types an incorrect password the text field will turn into a Single Line text box with the text "Incorrect Password". Then once they start typing again the text box will once again behave as a Password type text box.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that does what you want, it will display `Incorrect Password` in the `TextField` until the correct password is entered.

```
package 
{
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var tf:TextField = new TextField();

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);


            tf.border = true;
            tf.displayAsPassword = true;
            tf.multiline = false;
            tf.height = 20;
            tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            tf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            tf.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocusIn);

            addChild(tf);

        }

        private function onFocusIn(e:FocusEvent):void 
        {
            tf.text = "";
            tf.displayAsPassword = true;
        }

        private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {
            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
            {
                if (tf.text == "pass")
                {
                    trace("logged in");
                }
                else
                {
                    tf.displayAsPassword = false;
                    tf.text = "Incorrect Password";
                    stage.focus = stage;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```